# How to change the font size and style of font of individual array element

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, onclick, mouseevent

I am creating an interactive website where the user is able to click anywhere on the screen and a paragraph of text will show up in that exact mouse location. However I want these paragraphs to be in a different font and size. How will I incorporate this into my code. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
const texts = [
  "Paragraph: 1",
  "Paragraph: 2",
  "Paragraph: 3",
  "Paragraph: 4",
  "Paragraph: 5",
  "Paragraph: 6",
  "Paragraph: 7",
  "Paragraph: 8",
  "Paragraph: 9",
  "Paragraph: 10"
];

const classes = [
  "red",
  "blue",
  "red",
  "blue",
  "red",
  "blue",
  "red",
  "blue",
  "red",
  "blue"
];

// Keeps Track of Current Text
let currentParaIdx = 0;

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // Stop once All Texts are Displayed
  if (currentParaIdx === texts.length) return;

  const { clientX, clientY } = e; //get the click position

  //create the div
  const div = document.createElement("div");

  //set its text
  div.innerText = texts[currentParaIdx];

  //set its position and position style
  div.classList = classes[currentParaIdx];
  div.style.position = "absolute";
  div.style.left = clientX + "px";
  div.style.top = clientY + "px";
  currentParaIdx++;

  document.body.append(div); //add div to the page
});
```

I have been able to make the paragraphs different colours however i'm unsure how to change the font size and font style such as "times new roman" etc

Comment: you can give it an extra class, which you then use to style it how you want. You already have. Try adding something like `div.classList.add('special-class')` and on your css `.special-class { font-size: 20px !important }`

Comment: How would i edit each paragraph individually instead of one font size for all of it?

Comment: you could either give each a unique class name, or just style them in your JS with `div.style.fontSize = "14px"`